# can't scan into dest[2]: cannot scan int4 (OID 23) in binary format into *models.User

Tags: go, pgx

```
  type Order struct{
      Id uint `json:"id"`
      Items []Item
      Total float64
      CustomerID int32
      Address Address
      CreatedAt time.Time
      UpdatedAt time.Time
      Status orderstatus
    }
```

query :=   `INSERT INTO orders(items, total, address, customer_id, status, created_at) VALUES(@orderItems,@orderTotal,@orderAddress,@orderCustomerID,  @orderStatus,@orderCreatedAt) returning id, total, customer_id`;

```
 trans := pgx.NamedArgs{
          "orderItems": items,
          "orderTotal": float64(grandtotal),
          "orderAddress": address,
          "orderCustomer" : id,
          "orderStatus" : "Pending",
           "orderCreatedAt" : time.Now(),
          }

    err := database.DB.QueryRow(context.Background(),query,trans)
         .Scan(&order.Id, &order.Total, &order.CustomerID)
```

whenever i scan the customerID i get the error saying it cant be converted into a struct the customerID references Users(id) i tried to write struct that mentioned CustomerID as type of User and it failed too any help is highly appreciated  #golangbeginner

Comment: How exactly do you expect to map a 32 but unsigned int to a 32 but signed int?